# Read output of relay from gpio

Tags: gpio, python

I have an external board which ends in a simple relay.

I connected one wire to one GPIO pin and the other to GND.

I need to check status change of that pin. I'm working in python.

Thanks

Comment: Could you draw a diagram.  I'm not sure what is going on.  This probably isn't the right site for the question as it has almost nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The external board is an electrified fence controller. It has a normal open or normal close relay that gives tension when an alarm is happening. I need to read that from my gpio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that I understood the description correctly this is a circuit that should do the trick. Note the additional resistor (*pull-up*) compared to the way that is explained in the question. Without it the following happens: relays is open - Pi's input is "floating"; relays is closed - Pi's input is low. Which is why you are not detecting a proper change of state when the relays toggles. With the *pull-up* resistor a defined voltage level is applied to the input pin.

See also: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-guide/pull_up_down/ (note that they propose another series resistor to limit the current in the case the GPIO pin is set to output).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFiemd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You understood perfectly. I'll test it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.